# Lavrentiev Phenomenon

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, calculus-of-variations

Does there exist a (onedimensional) integral functional of calculus of variations 
$$
F(y)=\int_a^b f(t,y(t),y'(t))\,dt 
$$
such that not only
$$
\inf_{y\in Lip([a,b])}F(y)>\inf_{y\in W^{1,1}([a,b])}F(y)
$$
(that is, it shows the Lavrentiev phenomenon), but actually both the two $\inf$ are $\min$?

That is, both the two minimization problems have a solution but they are different?

Comment: And exactly what $f$ are allowed in this game?

Comment: I think that if $f$ can be only Borel, your idea in problem https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288336/lavrentiev-phenomenon-between-c1-and-lipschitz/288359#288359 with the function $f(t,y,ξ)$ to be 0 if y^3=|t| and F(y) otherwise, should work.

Comment: An example with $f$ Caratheodory/continuous (even polynomial) would be very interesting... the simplest example of Lav-phen is with a polynomial $f$.

Comment: I think that the paper of A. Ferriero (Action functionals that attain regular minima in presence of energy gaps, Discr. Cont. Dyn. Syst 2007, [link](http://cvgmt.sns.it/paper/10/))
may help.