# Lavrentiev phenomenon between $C^1$ and Lipschitz

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, calculus-of-variations

Does there exist a (onedimensional) integral functional of calculus of variations (with $f$ finite everywhere)
$$
F(y)=\int_a^b f(t,y(t),y'(t))\,dt 
$$
such that
$$
\inf_{y\in Lip([a,b])}F(y)<\inf_{y\in C^1([a,b])}F(y)
$$
that is, it shows the Lavrentiev phenomenon between $C^1$ and Lipschitz.

Comment: Is $f$ allowed to be unbounded discontinuous (like $1/y^2$ corrected to $0$ when $y=0$, say)?

Comment: yes, if the Lagrangian $f=f(x,y,\xi)$ is continuous or Caratheodory and bounded on bounded sets the two inf are the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Then trivially yes. Just take $F(y)=1+\sum_{q\in \mathbb Q}\frac{a_q}{|q-y|^2}$ with $a_q>0$ such that the series converges a.e. Then change all $+\infty$ values of $F$ to $1$. Now take $[a,b]=[-1,1]$ and define
$$
f(t,y,\xi) =
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if }y=|t|\\ 
F(y) &\text{otherwise}
\end {cases}.
$$
A Lipschitz function can just stay on the safe path $y=|t|$ and pay $0$ price for the trip, but a $C^1$ function will have to deviate from this path and either have $y\ne |t|$, $y'\ne 0$ at at least one point, which is enough to blow the integral up to $+\infty$, or stay constant, which gives the cost of at least $2$.

Comment: Since I will be possibly put this example in something that could be published, if you send me (in private) your name I could give you proper credit for that.

Comment: @CarloMantegazza Just quote MO. They'll benefit from the credit more than I ;-)