# Lavrentiev phenomenon between $C^1$ and $C^2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, calculus-of-variations

Does there exist a (onedimensional) functional that exhibits the Lavrentiev phenomenon between $C^1$ and $C^2$ that is

$$ F(y)=\int_a^b f(t,y(t),y'(t))\,dt \quad\text{or possibly}\quad F(y)=\int_a^b f(t,y(t),y'(t),y''(t))\,dt $$

such that

$$ \inf_{y\in C^1([a,b])}F(y)<\inf_{y\in C^2([a,b])}F(y) \;\;?$$

The paper "[Mantegazza - Some Elementary Questions in the Calculus of Variations](https://doi.org/10.4171/rsmup/73)" and the question [Lavrentiev phenomenon between $C^1$ and Lipschitz](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288336/lavrentiev-phenomenon-between-c1-and-lipschitz)
discuss the Lavrentiev phenomenon between $\mathrm{Lip}$ and $C^1$ but do not mention any higher classes.

Having no restrictions of $f$ could maybe give some possibility to construct an example, using some kind of function like $y(t)=t^{5/3}$…?

Comment: If you have a lower-regularity example between $C^1$ and Lipschitz, I think you can just apply that functional to $f'$.

Comment: Indeed, this way the example between **Lip** and $C^1$ immediately gives an example  between $C^{1,1}$ and $C^2$

Answer (score 1):

Does this example work? Take the domain to be $[0, 1]$. Let $H$ be the [Cantor function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), and $\mathcal H$ its graph. Define $f$ by
$$
f (t,x,y) =
\begin{cases}
0, &\text{if } (t, y) \in \mathcal H,\\
\max \left\{\dfrac{1}{\text{dist}((t, y), \mathcal H)}, 1\right\},&\text{otherwise}
.
\end{cases}
$$
Then the infimum of $F(g)$ over $g \in C^1$ is $0$, and is realised by taking $g(x) := \int_{0}^{x} H(s) ds$, but I believe the infimum over $C^2$ is $1$, and is realised by any $g$ such that $(t, g’(t))$ stays far away enough from $\mathcal H$.