# Lavrentiev phenomenon between $C^1$ + Lipschitz derivative and $C^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Denote by $\mathcal L$ the set of continuously differentiable real valued functions on $[0, 1]$ with Lipschitz continuous derivative. Does there exist a Borel measurable function $ f: [0, 1] \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb [0, \infty) $ such that

$$\inf_{g \in \mathcal L} \int_{0}^{1} f(t, g(t))  \ dt <  \inf_{h \in C^2([0, 1])} \ \int_{0}^{1} f(t, h(t)) \ dt?$$

*Note: Here the integrals are allowed to take the value $+\infty$.*

Comment: Don't you want to include $g'$ in the arguments of f?

Comment: Ah, I intend for $f$ to be independent of $g’$. If we include $g’$ the answer is yes, but the independent case seems much more subtle.

Comment: Let $u : [0,1] \to \mathbf{R}$ be a function in $C^{1,1} \setminus C^2$. It seems to me that modifying another [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288336/lavrentiev-phenomenon-between-c1-and-lipschitz?noredirect=1&lq=1) by changing the sentence to 'define $f(x,y,\xi) = 0$ if $y = u(x)$ and $F(y)$ otherwise' is valid. The 'safe path' that this answer refers to would now correspond to the graph of $u$. As any $C^2$-regular function deviates from this, it seems to me that $\int_0^1 f(x,g(x)) \, \mathrm{d} x = + \infty$ for every $g \in C^2$.

Comment: Ah, you are right of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited.

Let $g_0^\prime(x)=|x-1/2|,\; g_0(x)=\int_0^xg_1(t)dt,\; 0\leq x\leq1$.
Then $g_0$ has continuus derivative, namely $g_0^\prime$, which is Lipschitz,
but the second derivative is discontinuous. Let $L=\{(x,y):y=g_0(x)\}$
be the graph of $g_0$.

Now define $f(x,y)=0$ when $0\leq x\leq 1, y=g_0(x)$ and
$$f(x,y)=(\mathrm{dist}(x,y),L)^{-3}+1$$
otherwise.
Evidently $f$ is measurable, and
$\int_0^1 f(x,g_0(x))dx=0$, while $\int_0^1f(x,g(x))dx>c$ for every $C^2$ function $g$, where $c$ is an absolute constant.

Of course, the last fact requires an accurate proof, but on the other hand, it seems evident. Moreover, one can replace $3$ in the exponent
by some larger constant, to make it more evident. The idea is that when the graph of $g$ is too close to $L$, the integral is large.

Comment: Could you clarify what you intend for $f$ - there seems to be a typo? Also, the last claim seems very strong, could you provide some details? It seems a bit counterintuitive given that a $C^1$ can be approximated by $C^2$ functions. (Personally I thought that the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288336/lavrentiev-phenomenon-between-c1-and-lipschitz/288359#288359) given to a related question ought to apply here too.)

Comment: @Leo Moos - this would apply if there was a $g’$ in the argument for f, but the case where it depends only on $t, g$ is much more subtle.

Comment: @NateRiver I'm not sure I follow - the functional in the linked answer doesn't seem to depend on the derivative.

Comment: Oh what I meant was that if $g’$ was allowed here, we could emulate that construction with $g$ replaced by $g’$ and the proof would hold verbatim. But because we have only $g$ here, and the “regularity gap” is between $C^1$ + Lipschitz and $C^2$, the same proof won’t work.